# Property 'X' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx, solid-js

I had the following error when I use JSX sample code in TSX.

```
(property) use:sortable: true

Type '{ children: any; "use:sortable": true; class: string; classList: { "opacity-25": boolean; "transition-transform": boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.

  Property 'use:sortable' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)
```

ts(2322)

[image]

and

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(Element | ((activeDraggable: Draggable) => Element)) & Element'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(Element | ((activeDraggable: Draggable) => Element)) & Element'.ts(2322)
drag-overlay.d.ts(4, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DragOverlayProps & { children?: Element; }'
```

[image]

I tried

```
interface HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  "use:sortable": boolean
}
```

but, for some reason, nothing worked to avoid the error.

Any ideas?

The entire code is

Sortable list (vertical) in
https://solid-dnd.com/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom directives requires additional type annotations which is covered in the documentation:

> To register with TypeScript extend the JSX namespace.

```
declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Directives {
      model: [() => any, (v: any) => any];
    }
  }
}
```

Above code adds a custom directive called `model` which is used like so:

```html
<input type="text" use:model={[name, setName]} />
```

For more information please take a look at the custom directives section:

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#use___

Comment: Where should I have to add this 'd.ts' file place, I added `solid-js.d.ts` in root and added this line in `tsconfig.json` `"include": [
    "solid-js.d.ts" 
  ]` after adding this line now I'm getting error everywhere **Can not find name React**

Comment: Anywhere in your project. Check typescriipt documentation.